# Wagtail internationalization - add pages with other language

Tags: django, wagtail

I followed the steps from the official [wagtail documentation](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/i18n.html#configuration) to add a mulit-lingual django-app. So far I got one Page which indicates the language english. I added german to the wagtail.locales and want to translate the english page into german but I didn't find any input or select to change the pages's language.

Unforunatly I didn't found any example code on how to translate text.

I tried packages like wagtail-localize but those are not compatible with the latest version (v4.0.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wagtail-localize is by far the best option, a 4.x compatible update should be available within the next month.

I'd recommend staying with Wagtail 3.x for now in any case, 4.x has a lot of compatibility and usability issues.